# Is it correct to inject a Facebook SDK wrapper using InSingletonScope with Ninject?

Tags: ninject, facebook-c#-sdk, ninject-2

I have written a wrapper around the C# Facebook SDK usign the following code:

```
public interface IFacebookService
{
    Uri GetLoginUri(string returnUrl);

    FacebookResult OAuth(string url, string code);

    void Post(string message, string accessToken);
}
```

The implementation looks like:

```
public class FacebookService : IFacebookService
{
    public Uri GetLoginUri(string returnUrl)
    {
        var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);

        // code removed for simplicity

        return uri;
    }

    public FacebookResult OAuth(string url, string code)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;

        if (FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(url, out oauthResult))
        {
            // code removed for simplicity
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Post(string message, string accessToken)
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        // code removed for simplicity
    }
}
```

I use Ninject to inject this where needed to perform login using oauth and posting to the users Facebook wall.

I currently have this configured using:

```
kernel.Bind<IFacebookService>().To<FacebookService>().InSingletonScope();
```

Is it correct to use InSingletonScope? Since this is a third party library I am not sure if this is the right approach since all threads will share the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no knowledge about the Facebook SDK. But as a general rule if the implementation is stateless then singleton is the correct scope. I assume this is the case with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it is necessary to create a new interface to deal with FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl or FacebookOAuthResult.Parse

GetLoginUrl and ParseResult of FacebookOAuthClient are already virtual. (make sure you are at least on v5.0.35 to get the FacebookOAuthClient.ParseResult which does the same thing as FacebookOAuthResult.Parse.)

Then use constructor injection of ninject to set the IFacebookApplication for FacebookOAuthClient.

you could also use contructor injection to set the access token for FacebookClient. (that is unless u want to have easier methods for posting to wall and so on.)
Or you could also do without the access token, and set FacebookClient.AccessToken = "access_token"